# Weird Logic Pro quirk with scoring

Tags: logic-pro

I have an issue with the score display in Logic Pro X (10.3.2).

Consider the following chords (F#m and E6) that last a full bar each:

[image: Notes]

When switching to the score representation, I see the following:

[image: Score]

and if I add a new bar, I get this:

[image: Empty bar]

While it's accurate, it doesn't make sense to display it that way.

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Logic pro isn't really for engraving sheet music so quirks like this are somewhat understandable. It's more normal  than the "chord detector" they have.

Comment: There is so many bug in all that software that this is just a little issue.

Answer (score 1):

What I can gather visually, your new bar contains a simplified rest notation rhythm as the second bar of your chords, specifically, there you have an E6 chord rhythmicised as dotted quaver + two 16ths + a half note, which is more accurately represented as in the second bar, namely, quaver + dotted 8th + 16th + half note.

It seems like the chord notation got messed up somehow, but you can try to repair it with view parameters.

Comment: How can the view parameters fix it? I've toggled some of the settings back and forth, but to no avail

Comment: @Thomas have you tried using separate duplicate that's quantized? It helps with scoring view

Comment: that issue ended up being random; some changes in the project would trigger a different representation.